# How can I call a inner function from the Python shell?

Tags: python, nested, private-methods

I have some code (that I can't easily modify), of the following form:

```
def foo(x):
   do_other_stuff_that_I_do_not_want_to_do()
   def bar():
      "do something"
      str(x)
   bar()
```

I would like to call `bar()`, directly, from the Python shell.  I don't mind using `co_globals`, or other internal bits.  I have the feeling that this may be impossible; is it?

Comment: The last thing that foo does is invoke bar, why not just call foo()?

Comment: @paul because foo() does other stuff besides call bar(), that I don't want to do.

Comment: "that I can't easily modify"  Often false.  Try talking to the author.

Comment: well, this is mostly just for expirmenting purposes -- if I were to actually submit it to the project (rdiff-backup), I'd certainly ask for the necessary changes to let me reuse all the code possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It *is* impossible to get at the inner function object with the code as you've stated it -- said object is only created (by the `def` statement) when the outer function *runs* (i.e., when it gets called).

As an aside, note that outer functions like `foo` are often coded to *return* the inner function as their result (e.g. by changing `bar()` to `return bar`) as the last line, exactly to work as "function factories" (often, as "closure factories") rather than keep the very existence of an internal function as a kind of private, secret implementation detail; but your coding picks the latter route instead.

**Edit**...:

It *is* possible to get at the *code* object for the inner function, however:

```
>>> def outer():
...   def inner(): return 'boo'
...   print inner()
... 
>>> eval(outer.func_code.co_consts[1])
'boo'
>>>
```

However, in general, to make a code object into a callable function requires considerable work (in this special case an `eval` suffices because the inner function has no arguments nor any nonlocal variables, but of course that's *not* anywhere even *close* to the general case... in which you do have to supply such niceties as bindings for nonlocals!-)

Comment: Hm.  That's what I thought.  However, it is possible to access the code object for the inner function (via `func_code.co_consts`), which leads to the question -- can I evaluate that code object?  Answer: yes, with eval().  But it complains about free variables...

Comment: thanks!  The next step is figuring out how to provide the free variable to the code object.  Should I make a new question to ask that, or continue in this question?

Comment: @Jesse, it's hard enough that I recommend you open a separate Q!

Comment: Will do.  Or I may just give up on it for now; I **can** just copy&paste the code, after all... ;-)  Thanks so much for the help!